# Changing My Full Name in Cyprus

Tags: name

I’m planning to change my full name as soon as I can.
So can someone walk me through the whole procedure?

I’m located in Cyprus.

Comment: Each European country has its own laws concerning name change.  To get a decent answer, you'll need to be more specific about your location.

Comment: It looks like Cyprus allows name changes only to its citizens.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a citizen of Cyprus, [you fill out the name change affidavit](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-can-you-legally-change-your-name-cyprus-a-g-paphitis-co-llc-/) on a form available form your District Administrative Office before a notary, submit it with 80 Euros, and hope that the Registrar at the District Administrative Office approves your application.

Your affidavit will state, among other things, your proposed name, which must be acceptable by Cyprus standards, and your reason for the change, which probably shouldn't be "to assist me in avoiding an outstanding warrant for my arrest for murder and high treason against the government of Cyprus" or "to steal the identity of my next door neighbor."

If it is approved, you are done and can now go about the arduous process of changing your name with everyone you need to do business with from bank accounts to property registries to ID cards and passports to leases to car titles to professional licenses.

If it isn't, you figure out why and either change your application accordingly or see if you can find an attorney to help you contest the denial in the appropriate tribunal.

If you are not a citizen of Cyprus, you probably need to go to the country in the E.U. where you are a citizen, if there is one.

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking your time. What did you mean by “name acceptable by Cyprus standards” ? They can decline the name change to names they don’t like?

Comment: And the MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION, Where do I find the form to fill out? The office is located over 100 kilometers away from me so I have to drive all the way there to just get the form??

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Almost every country in Europe has a list of criteria for acceptable names for their citizens (some even require you to choose from a specific list) and they can decline name changes to names that don't meet that criteria. "Where do I find the form to fill out?", is beyond the scope of Law.SE. I would call your closest District Administrative Office and ask.

Comment: Got it, so for instance to change ones name to something like John, William or Ryan gotta have citizenship in US/UK ?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov I have no idea precisely what rules Cyprus has, but, for example, it may require that names be in Cyrillic characters, and it might very well rule out some of the names you list. What names are acceptable in Cyprus is really a distinct issue from how you change your name.